# What should be the DataType of Controller's Action method for JSon type posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know that what should be the `datatype` of Controller Action Paramter's for JSon post value?

I'm posting the form using **jQuery.Post** method...

**E.g.**

```
jQuery.post('/Customer/PostData', jQuery(document.forms[0]).serialize(), function (data) {
alert('Successfully post..!');
});
```

I want to add another parameter with post data.. let's say I also want to post `CustomerID` along with `form data JSON`..

Could you please let me know what should I keep my controller paramter's datatype? I tried with `List<string,string>` as a controller's paramter data type , but it is not working.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a hidden field to your form containing the value you would like to send:

```
<%= Html.Hidden("CustomerID") %>
```

and then:

```
$('#CustomerID').val('123');
var dataToPost = $(document.forms[0]).serialize();
$.post('/Customer/PostData', dataToPost, function (data) {
    alert('Successfully post..!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Right but I want to pass CustomerID as a another parameter with jQUERY post method..

Comment: @nunu, what do you mean by another parameter? You want to modify the value of some form input field before posting?

Comment: And of course, could you please let me know that what should be the paramter dataType for Controller's method?

Comment: @nunu, this will depend on what are the possible values: Int32, Guid, string, ... It depends on the possible values of your `CustomerID`.

Comment: No, I don't want to modify anything, As I have Serialize Form data, I want to post another parameter for Customer ID, separate from form data. I want to post separate variable for CustomerID in jQuery.POST method..

Comment: @nunu, well in this case you could add a hidden field inside the form you are posting as I explained in my answer. When you call `$(form).serialize()` this value will automatically be included in the POST and you will be able to retrieve it inside your controller action: `public ActionResult Foo(string customerId) { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please let me know what If I'm posting a $(form).serialize() by jQuery form post, what would be the DataType of controller method's paramter dayaType? $(form).serialize() post NameValueCollection type data... What would I keep datatype for my controller's parameter?

Comment: @nunu, it depends what data does your form contains. For example if you have an input fields called `foo.bar` inside your form you could write a custom class as action parameter which has a property `Foo` which itself is a custom class having property `Bar`. The default model binder will automatically map the values.

Comment: Thanks.. Let's say If I'm posting $(form).serialize() by jQuery post, What should I keep my Controller's method parameter datatype? I tried by Dictionary<string,string>, but it is not working.. I want controller's method paramter datatype for $(form).serialize().

Comment: @nunu, you could create a custom view model.